# Append websocket data to a list in python

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to record some websocket data to a list and perform operations on it. The list are created but with the wrong data. should I use redis to store the data and perform the operation ? I want to perform operation 'on the fly' and take actions if a condition is met. so it should be as fast as possible.

here is the code :

```
import json                                                              
import websocket 
import asyncio



this = json.dumps({'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'ticker', 'market': 'BTC/USD'})                      
this2 = json.dumps({'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'ticker', 'market': 'ETH/USD'}) 

vx = list()
def sav(ps):
  vx.append(ps)
  list2 = [x for x in vx if x != []]
  last_element = list2[-1]
  #print(last_element)
  return last_element
  
def on_open(wsapp):   
  tickers = "BTC/USD"
  wsapp.send(json.dumps({'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'ticker', 'market': tickers}))
  wsapp.send(this2)

def on_message(wsapp, message):                                                   
  #print(message)                                                          
  btc = list()
  eth = list()
  response = json.loads(str(message))

  if response['market'] == "BTC/USD":                    
    resp1 = response['data']['bid']
    
    btc.append(resp1)
    
    print(f'ask price btc :', resp1)
    
  else:
    resp2 = response['data']['ask']
    eth.append(resp2)
    print(f'bid price ETH/USD :', resp2)

  print(f'r btc', btc)
  print(f'r eth', eth)
  sav(btc)
  sav(eth)
  
  # I'm trying to divide btc by eth like that :
  print(sav(btc)/sav(eth))
  
  
  # print(vx)
wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp('wss://ftx.com/ws/', on_message=on_message, on_open=on_open)
wsapp.run_forever()
```

the script return two list but the data is wrong. and nothing is printed when I try to divide btc / eth. I want the list for btc/usd and eth to be populated with the last data received in order to perform calculations but it looks like the function "On_message" reset the lists each time it's called.

```
ask price btc : 38125.0
r btc [38125.0]
r eth []
[38125.0]
[38125.0]
bid price ETH/USD : 2659.1
r btc []
r eth [2659.1]
[2659.1]
[2659.1]
ask price btc : 38125.0
r btc [38125.0]
r eth []
[2659.1]
[38125.0]
bid price ETH/USD : 2659.0
r btc []
r eth [2659.0]
[2659.0]
[2659.0]
```

Comment: do you means list `btc` and `eth`? You use `btc = list()`, `eth = list()` in `on_message()` - so YOU  reset the lists. You should create them outside `on_message` - like `vx`

Comment: if list is empty (ie. `eth`) then `list2[-1]` in `sav(eth)` will raise error  - but `websocket` may have own `try/except` to catch it (to work even if there are problems) and it doesn't show you this error. And because `list2[-1]` in `sav(eth)` can raise error so it will skip code after `sav(eth)` - so it will not run also `print(sav(btc)/sav(eth))`

Comment: you could use more `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed.

Comment: if you add `websocket.enableTrace(True)  ` at start then it will display all errors and logging messages.

Comment: BTW: `sav()` returns list so `sav(btc)/sav(eth)` works like `[124.0] / [256.0]` but you can't divide two lists - try `[124.0] / [256.0]` and you get another error.

Comment: your help was useful, I've managed to bypass the problem by using a pandas dataframe. I still think there is a better way to do this with a proper use of classes maybe.

Comment: at this moment you mess with lists. You clear list at the beginning of `on_message` so every message remove previous content. In `sav()` you return list (with single value) but it looks like you expect directly this single value without list - to divide `124.0 / 256.0` but you get `[124.0] / [256.0]`. Using `print()`, `print(type(..))` you could see all problems.